# Shrink span when Text is small with col-md classes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want `<span>` to shrink to small possible and but take max width as allocated by respective `col-md-*`.
I want all that to be in one row, so i have assigned each `span` some `col-md-*`. Overlapping should not be visible, mean if `article name` is bigger then its okay to be truncated from display.

```
<div style="" ng-repeat="">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <span class="col-md-2"><a href="">User Name</a></span>
    <span class="col-md-3">created New Article</span>
    <span class="col-md-5"><a href="">A new Article name for my next article.</a></span>
    <span class="col-md-2">on Web Designing</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row-fluid pull-right">
    <span class="col-md-12 pull-right">Timestamp</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/errhunter/dfufu058/)

Current Output
[https://jsfiddle.net/errhunter/dfufu058/embedded/result/](https://jsfiddle.net/errhunter/0f33ddLL/embedded/result/)

Expected output
https://jsfiddle.net/errhunter/0f33ddLL/embedded/result/
In expected i removed all bootstrap class `col-md-*`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this css to your row-fluid should solve the problem.

```
.row-fluid {
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: It makes it one row, but it does not shrink the space taken by each fields. Check expected output. TY for trying.

Comment: Yes , because col-md-* adds right and left padding. You should those classes if you don't want padding.

Comment: If i dont use those classes, i wont get its responsive width.